# VSCode deleted the folder where my project was

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had my project in VS Code's installation directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code) because I don't like that any files related to a program placed all over the PC. Then I decided to update VSCode. After the update the folder where my project was, has gone. Are there any ways to restore it? Atleast some of the files? I'm using Windows 7 and don't have any Git accounts.

Windows build-in restoration tool gives me 1 week old folder of my project. I did alot since then. Sometimes you shouldn't work too hard.

Comment: Harsh lesson to realise version control is a must-have for any project...

Comment: You should have turned off your computer immediatly, boot on a GNU/Linux livecd and use tools such as photorec, even grep'ing through your hard drive could have done the trick. But it's probably too late by now (you can still try, you might get something back if you're lucky enough).

Comment: @Olaf how would that help unless you bend over backward to put the VCS internals separate from the working directory where they wouldn't also be removed during a VS Code update?

Comment: @starball The question here is if he can retrieve the deleted files. With a remote backup this would be the case. Would it be a working solution to use going forward VC in the VSCode dir? Probably not.

Comment: of course not. I agree that a lesson should be learned here not to do this again. but the question here is _how to restore the files_. VCS is only a solution if you back up to a remote it proactively, and the question post seems to indicate that they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to look if there is any backup of your windows 7 computer to recover your file.

Comment: what.... does this even mean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i got the same problem, when VS Code updates it updates also its installation directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code, which means any file you create in the installation directory gets deleted, so that's why the Project folder got deleted. It is best to keep your project folders and files in your system for example C:\Projects.. Alternatively you can always use version control ie Git to ensure safety of your code